# mysql_real_escape_string is not working in one server

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string('tientrer') ;?>
```

The above code is return an empty string in one server but is working fine in other servers. Why is it so?

Comment: Are you connecting with mysql function on both?

Comment: Because the bible tells you so! Without telling us the differences between the servers, how can you expect us to answer? And why are you doing it in the first place?

Comment: servers php version = 5.5?

Comment: If you are using mysqli->mysqli_real_escape_string.If its PDO use prepared statements.

Comment: Can you post the complete code snippet including connection to db?

Answer (score 1):

Wildly random guess:

You are not connecting to a database using `mysql_connect`. `mysql_real_escape_string` needs a database connection to do its job (because you are escaping *for the database*; you **are** escaping this *for a database query*, right?!). If no connection exists yet, it'll try to establish one automatically using a standard username and password. On one server this standard password works, on another it doesn't.

Comment: No the query works without mysql_real_escape_string function , which means there is no database connection problem

Comment: Any you *are* connected to the database at the time you call `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Answer (score 0):

you are escaping a string ?

you mean maybe like that

```
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($tientrer) ;?>
```

to escape the variable `tientrer` if its a variable.

EDIT:

then maybe the server which not working maybe the mysql is deprecated there , try change to mysqli or pdo

Comment: No the problem is the function always returns an empty string in one server. The same is working in other servers

Comment: then maybe the server which not working maybe the mysql is deprecated there , try change to mysqli .

Comment: I have tried mysqli too. Its not working either

Comment: how its not working any errors ? have you tried to make errors on. ?

Comment: try this `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and say what erros it saids.